# Alfresco ADF 3.5.0 - Angular7 : composant doesn't appear in production

Tags: angular, build, alfresco

I use Angular 7.2, adf-content-services 3.5.0, adf-core 3.5.0 and js/api 3.5.0
I use the following alfresco composent in a angular html component:

```
<adf-userinfo class="adf-app-layout-user-profile" [menuPositionX]="'before'" [menuPositionY]="'above'">
  </adf-userinfo>
```

I have a scss file with it.

It works nice in local :-)  :

[image]

But when I build the project and I start tomcat, the composent doesn't appear :

[image]

What is missing ?

I don't understand the "build" mechanism very well so I compare config files  with an other projet where this composent appears in production but I don't find the problem

**EDIT**
The element appears in markup and there is no error message in console

[image]

Comment: Well, I am not sure I will be able to help, but it would be good to know if (1) the element appears in the markup and (2) whether the console is error free when you serve the prod bundle.

Comment: yes, the element appears and there is non error message in console (cf edit)